# Моментальное выполнение в timeout

Tags: javascript

Показали код из сторонней библиотеки.
Какие тонкие моменты могли заставить автора в таймауте поставить время ноль?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    //todo something
}, 0);
```

Comment: Возможно это нужно чтобы запустить новый поток в вашем коде? Эта фунция будет выполняться долго ?

Comment: [немного](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-timing-depth#делаем-события-асинхронными-через-settimeout-0) про этот способ добиться асинхронности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот способ может понадобиться, если потребуется асинхронное выполнение кода.

Например

```
   console.log("1");
   console.log("2");
   console.log("3");
```

выведет, как и предполагается: **1 2 3**

Однако, при добавлении *setTimeout* получится: **1 3 2**

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("2");
}, 0);
console.log("3"); // > 1 3 2
```

Это связано с тем, что выполнение функции откладывается до следующего витка **event loop**.

Comment: Вы путаете причину со следствием. Порядок выолнения связан не с тем, что `setTimeout` имеет задержку, а с тем, что выполнение функции откладывается до следующего витка **event loop**. Само значение задержки может быть абсолютно любым, все зависит от текущей загрузки движка JS.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev благодарю за разъяснение. Если что-то считаете ещё дополнить стоит, поправьте ответ.